# Is it possible to perform validation on a field amended after initialisation of the model?

Tags: python, pydantic

The below:

```
import pydantic as pdc

class Test(pdc.BaseModel):
        
    test: int | None
        
test = Test(test=None)
test.test = "10"
    
print(type(test.test))
```

Results in `<class 'str'>`.

Is it possible to ensure that validation is performed on a field amended after initialisation of the model?